# If Product Disable Not An Deleted Then Product Redirect To Parent Category in magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, backend

I have disable product in back end then product is redirect to here parent category. I clearly say product is not and deleted only disable product can redirect to here parent category.

Comment: Your problem is not very clear. What is it exactly that you are trying to accomplish? Can you try explain in steps?

Comment: Ya sure i have explain you, first of all i have going at back end  and goto catalog > product and open the 1product,after that i have disable this product and clear the cache after that i have move on front end and search this product that time  product not redirect to 404 error page,but this product can redirect to his parent category.do you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using an Observer.

Use an observer to watch the event `controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view`. You can check if product has status `Disabled` and redirect to the last category.

More info and a code example here: http://evgv.github.io/magento/redirect/categories/product/observer/2016/04/27/redirect-from-disabled-product-to-last-product-category.html